# How can I get objectID against my required document and store it in a variable using groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I intend to get objectID against a particular document in mongodb, store it in a variable and print it on console.Mind it I want complete value in _id field i-e:  ObjectId("5dc2b032da7bec484cc0be5b") as I intend to use this value as filter in my next sampler.
 I have written the following code but it fails:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;

import org.bson.Document;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

//import java.util.Arrays;

try {


MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

    Document document = new Document("EmployeeID",12345)
        .append("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter")
        .append("Employee_Type_OID",4)
        .append("Rank",0)
        .append("Rating",0)
        .append("Score",0)
        .append("BOSS_OID",56789)
        .append("CompanyID","012345T");

    collection.insertOne(document);


Document result = collection.find(eq("EmployeeID",12345)).first();
String ID =result.get("_id");   
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(ID);
return "Document inserted"+ objectId; 



    }
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

IAm getting following error:

```
 Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
```

Comment: In your code check these lines: 
```ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(ID);

return "Document inserted"+ objectID;```
Defined variable objectId and returned variable objectID has different cases.

Comment: Oh i figured that out later but issue is not there as I have correct that still I dnt get the required value @RahulSharma I get  following :

Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you're getting the `result` variable is [`null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) therefore my expectation is that your [`find` operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) fails somewhere somehow. Check out [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries.

Once you solve your problem with insertion/finding of the document you should be able to store it using [`vars` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
vars.put('myID', objectId as String)
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: ` Document result = 
     collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID",1111111)).first();
     if(result !=null){
     String ID =result.get("_id");   
     ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(ID);
      vars.put('myID', objectId as String);
      log.info (vars.get('myID'))
       return objectId; 
        }
        return "Employee not found";`
now i am writing the above code still not getting the correct value of _id i-e ObjectId("5dc2cbc6da7bec484cc0be9e")

I am just getting following part in log:
5dc2cbc6da7bec484cc0be9e

Comment: ` db.getCollection('example').aggregate([ { "$project": { "_id": 0, "id": "$_id" } } ])` have you tried using aggregate